# Save the selected value of a drop down in global variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

How can I save the value of a selected dropdown in a global variable in MVC.I have to save the changed value in a variable named "no_of_days" whenever the value is changed.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    string no_of_days = "6";
}
<body>
   <div class="document_dashboard_dropdown ms-Dropdown" tabindex="0">
      <i class="ms-Dropdown-caretDown ms-Icon ms-Icon--caretDown"></i>
      <select id="no_of_days" class="ms-Dropdown-select">
         <option value="6" class="ms-Dropdown-item " selected="selected">last 6 months</option>
          <option value="7" class="ms-Dropdown-item">last 7 months</option>
                <option value="8" class="ms-Dropdown-item">last 8 months</option>
                <option value="9" class="ms-Dropdown-item">last 9 months</option>
                <option value="10" class="ms-Dropdown-item">last 10 months</option>
                <option value="11" class="ms-Dropdown-item">last 11 months</option>
                <option value="12" class="ms-Dropdown-item">last year</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#no_of_days').change(function () {
        '@no_of_days'=$('#no_of_days').val()
       });
    });
</script>
```

I am not able to get any value in @no_of_days variable. I want to do a Ajax.ActionLink call so I need the real-time value of @no_of_days

Comment: Why do you need globals? Hands off...

Comment: `no_of_days` is a variable in your C# code, so to get JS to fill that you'd need to use AJAX

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't get what you are trying to say

Comment: Please read the question I marked as duplicate for more information

Comment: I am sorry I was unable to get any help from the reference post you gave me. It is not the same question that I am asking. I am aspiring to know how I could get the selected dropdown item in the html itself and not by script.